# Issue token to logged in user via spring

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring (3.2) based web app that a user can log into.  The site will also provide an API secured via OAuth 2.0.  My question then, is how do I go about generating a token for a logged in user?

The underlying idea here is that there will be a mobile app that opens up a web frame to the login page, which will eventually redirect to a url schema with an oauth token that the app will catch and then use for the api calls.  Looking at the code for [TokenEndpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html), I see that it defers token creation to a list of [TokenGranter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/TokenGranter.html) types.  Should I be creating my own [TokenGranter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/TokenGranter.html) extended class, or am I looking at this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a controller like this:

```
 OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest
                .authorizationLocation(csOauthAuthorizeUrl)
                .setClientId(csClientId)
                .setRedirectURI(
                        UrlLocator.getBaseUrlBuilder().addSubpath(AUTH_CODE_HANDLER_URL).asUnEscapedString())
                .setResponseType("code")
                .buildQueryMessage();

        UrlUtils.temporarilyRedirect(httpResponse, request.getLocationUri());
        return null;
```

Then handling the code returned.  My big problem here was that I had the /oauth/authorize endpoint set to use client credentials.  Once I realized that tokens were being issued for the client ID instead of the user, it started to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the Authorization Flow of OAuth. Spring has already support that, if you have configured the spring-security-oauth correctly, you just have to redirect the user/your mobile apps to `/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=code` this will redirect user to authorization page, if user has not login yet, it will redirect the user to login page then to the authorization page.

After the user completed the authorization process, it will redirect the user to an already registered redirect_url parameter with the authorization_code 'yourapp.com/callback?code=xxxx'.

Your application should exchange this authorization_code with the real token access to `/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxx&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxx`

After that you will receive the token access that can be used to access the resource server.